# how can I align the red shape and black shape in parallel?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

how can I align the red shape and black shape in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

Draw 1 shape.

Duplicate it while dragging

Then duplicate it again.

Use Pathfinder or Shape Builder to merge and cut area.

[image]

Or to create the smaller chevron after the larger shape has already been drawn, drag the opposite direction when duplicating....

[image]

(Note Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> while dragging -- <kbd>Shift</kbd> to constrain the drag horizontally, and <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> to duplicate the object.)

Comment: They already have their shapes and are asking how to adjust them.

Comment: The delete the red.. and follow the second animation in my answer. Not sure what the issue with that may be.

Comment: Oh the issue I see is the question is "How do I align these things" and you answered "here is how you draw them new". He has shapes he may need to keep.

Comment: I guess I should have *explicitly* stated.. "don't bother trying align things, jsut create a shape which will be parallel." Oh well, thanks for the down vote. Always nice to be helpful and get a down vote :)

Comment: Sorry, it won't let me undo the vote. I'll go vote up some of your other stuff.